# Javascript error in Internet explorer for sharepoint sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am having a SharePoint blog site. When i am trying to create a post on the blog using Internet explorer, i am getting the JavaScript error as below on the left bottom corner.

But if i revert the site to 2007 look and feel, i am able to create the post. But after doing the visual upgrade to 2010, we are unable to create the post

Error : `"null" is null or not an object.`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The error is too generic and require more information to catch the root cause of issue.

First thing is to restart the browser. Even then it doesn't resolve then go for second option.

Secondly debugging the issue. This can be achieved in many ways.

1. Enable script debugging option in browser. Then after refresh you will get an option to debug in the IDE that is available in your machine.
2. If you have Developer Tool bar available in your browser then the Console window will give you more information about the error like line number etc

Hope this helps you!